# Isolated Storage - delayed and wrong working

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm writing my first app in WP7 and I have strange problem with IS:

```
                case "pn_s":            
                IsolatedStorageFile isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                //IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = isoStorage.CreateFile("plan_zajec_pn.txt"); 
                IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(("plan_zajec_pn.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, isoStorage);
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream);
                string dane="";
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    dane += godzina[i].Text;
                    dane += ";";
                    dane += przedmiot[i].Text;
                    dane += ";";
                    dane += sala[i].Text;
                    dane += ";";
                }
                writer.WriteLine(dane);
                isoStream.Close();
                break;
```

Actually it doesn't work... 
File create after I re-open application but it's empty, I've checked "dane" and it contains date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a `StreamWriter`, you mustn't close the underlying stream, or the writer may not have enough time to write all the data. Just close the writer, and it'll take care of closing the stream. Also, you should enclose your streams in `using` statement to close them even if an error is thrown.

In the end, your code should look like:

```
case "pn_s":            
    using (var isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(("plan_zajec_pn.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, isoStorage))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
            {
                string dane = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    dane += godzina[i].Text;
                    dane += ";";
                    dane += przedmiot[i].Text;
                    dane += ";";
                    dane += sala[i].Text;
                    dane += ";";
                }

                writer.WriteLine(dane);
            }
        }
    }

    break;
```